# Save a foreign key in postgreSQL using python-django

Tags: django, postgresql, python-2.7

I'm trying to a save a foreign key inside an object into my db using a form, but i get the error : 'Syntax isn't valid for integer', I discovered that postgreSQL save the foreign key as an id, how can i save it then?

Here it is my code.

Models.py :

```
class treballador(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, unique=True)
    cognom = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False)
    tipusDocID = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TIPUSDOC, null=False)
    docId = models.CharField(max_length=9, null=False)
    tlf_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\d{9,9}$',message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 9 digits allowed.")
    tlf = models.CharField(validators=[tlf_regex], blank=True, max_length=9)  # validators should be a list
    correu = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    ciutat = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    dataDAlta = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.nom) or unicode(self.id)

class despesa(models.Model):
    nomTreballador = models.ForeignKey(treballador, to_field='nom')
    tipusDeGast = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=GASTOS)
    quantia = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    data = models.DateTimeField()
```

forms.py:

```
class desModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    data = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y'), label="Data de la despesa", input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'])

    class Meta:
        model= despesa
        fields= ["nomTreballador","tipusDeGast","quantia","data"]

        def clean_despesa(self):
            despeses = self.cleaned_data.get("tipusDeGast")
            return despeses

        def clean_date(self):
            date = self.cleaned_data.get("data")
            return date

        def clean_quantia(self):
            quantia = self.cleaned_data.get("quantia")
            return quantia

        def clean_nom(self):
            nomTreballador = self.cleaned_data.get("nomTreballador")
            return nomTreballador

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(desModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["nomTreballador"].queryset=treballador.objects.all().distinct()
```

views.py:

```
def home(request):
    form = desModelForm(request.POST or None)

    context = {
        "gast_form": form
    }


    if form.is_valid():

        desp = form.save(commit=False)

        desp.save()



    return render(request, "imputacioDespeses.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `to_field='nom'` from the `nomTreballador` ForeignKey field and it will insert the `Treballador`'s primary key (an integer) instead of `nom` (which is a string).

Answer (score 1):

Your foreign key field is the problem.
Remove to_field and Django will automatically map it to ID

```
nomTreballador = models.ForeignKey(treballador)
```